# Term symbols in transition metals and lanthanides

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

Hello I was researching a little about term symbols of lanthanides and transition metals and have got two questions.

It is known that lanthanides don’t follow LS-coupling, but instead JJ-coupling. Does that mean that the term symbols for the rare earth (III) cations in the famous Diecke diagram are formed by JJ-coupling? I am asking because the ground state term symbols for lanthanides are found just like the transition metal ground states:

[image]

My second question is the following: In the term schemes for transition and lanthanide metals, all filled shells and subshells are discarded, so we are only looking at d-d-transitions and f-f-transitions of their respective term symbols if I understood correctly.

But below the f- and d-orbitals there are other orbitals (for example 2s) which could also do electronic transitions (at much higher energies of course). How are they described?

Comment: For readers, see also Wikipedia articles [Angular momentum coupling - Spin-orbit coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum_coupling#Spin%E2%80%93orbit_coupling) and [Spin-orbit interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin%E2%80%93orbit_interaction) // [Possible source of the diagram on researchgate.net](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Dieke-diagram-of-the-energy-levels-of-some-trivalent-lanthanide-ions-The-main-emissive_fig2_33496710)

Comment: You can have a look at the NIST webpages, especially on the [compendium on atomic spectroscopy](https://www.nist.gov/pml/atomic-spectroscopy-compendium-basic-ideas-notation-data-and-formulas) and the [atomic level database](https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/ASD/levels_form.html).

Comment: As you write, the filled orbitals do not contribute as spin ang mom is zero, those lower energy ones with unpaired electrons as part of an excited state will add in in just the same way as any other.

Comment: So not only can we describe the outermost electrons with the term symbols, but any other electron in an lanthanide, for example electrons in the 4s shell? Just like main group elements